# October CMS limit pages in pagination

Tags: php, content-management-system, octobercms

I would like to ask how can I limit pages for example if I want only 4 pages in pagination and then arrows. Now it shows the all pages:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Uehz.png)

and this is code I'm using now:

```html
{% if posts.lastPage > 1 %}
  <div class="pagination">
      <ul>
          {% if posts.currentPage > 1 %}
              <li><a class="pagination--left-arrow"href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (posts.currentPage-1) }) }}">&larr;</a></li>
          {% endif %}

          {% for page in 1..posts.lastPage %}
              <li class="{{ posts.currentPage == page ? 'active' : null }}">
                  <a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): page }) }}">{{ page }}</a>
              </li>
          {% endfor %}

          {% if posts.lastPage > posts.currentPage %}
              <li><a class="pagination--right-arrow"href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (posts.currentPage+1) }) }}">&rarr;</a></li>
          {% endif %}
      </ul>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: you may add middle loop like `{% set toPage = posts.currentPage + 3 %} {% for page in posts.currentPage..toPage %}` .. and add default value for currentPage means if its not set set it to 1 .. or so

Comment: and adjust variables so `the current page` button stays at the middle not at the first maybe...

Answer (score 0):

This is my code. I hope it can have you. Its work but it need to optimize, I don't have more time for it, so you can update it.

Flow:

```
    {% if lastPage <= 5 %}
        {% for item in 1..lastPage %}
            {% if currentPage == item %}
                <li><span>{{ item }}</span></li>
            {% else %}
                <li><a href="{{ paginator.url(item) }}">{{ item }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {% if currentPage >= 1 and currentPage < 4 %}
            {% for item in 1..4 %}
                {% if currentPage == item %}
                    <li><span>{{ item }}</span></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li><a href="{{ paginator.url(item) }}">{{ item }}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            <li  class="disabled not-active"><a href="#">...</a></li>
            {% for item in (lastPage-2)..lastPage %}
                {% if currentPage == item %}
                    <li><span>{{ item }}</span></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li><a href="{{ paginator.url(item) }}">{{ item }}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}  
        {% elseif currentPage >= 4 and currentPage < lastPage - 1  %}
            {% if currentPage == firstPage %}
                <li><span>{{ firstPage }}</span></li>
            {% else %}
                <li><a href="{{ paginator.url(firstPage) }}">{{ firstPage }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            <li  class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
            {% for item in currentPage-1..currentPage+1 %}
                {% if currentPage == item %}
                    <li><span>{{ item }}</span></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li><a href="{{ paginator.url(item) }}">{{ item }}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            <li  class="disabled not-active"><a href="#">...</a></li>
            {% if currentPage == lastPage %}
                <li><span>{{ lastPage }}</span></li>
            {% else %}
                <li><a href="{{ paginator.url(lastPage) }}">{{ lastPage }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            {% if currentPage == firstPage %}
                <li><span>{{ firstPage }}</span></li>
            {% else %}
                <li><a href="{{ paginator.url(firstPage) }}">{{ firstPage }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            <li  class="disabled not-active"><a href="#">...</a></li>
            {% for item in lastPage-2..lastPage%}
                {% if currentPage == item %}
                    <li><span>{{ item }}</span></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li><a href="{{ paginator.url(item) }}">{{ item }}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

    {% endif %}

    <li><a href="{{ hasMorePages ? nextPageUrl : '#' }}" class="{{ hasMorePages ? '' : 'not-active' }}"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `|slice` could be used.

**Example**

```
{% for page in posts|slice(posts.currentPage, 4) %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used at home and slightly modified your code. Everything is working )

```html
        {# Pagination #}
        {% if posts.lastPage > 1 %}
            <ul class="pagination">
            {# First page #}
            {% if posts.currentPage > 3 %}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (posts.firstPage) }) }}"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {# Previous page #}
            {% if posts.currentPage > 3 %}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (posts.currentPage-1) }) }}"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {# Page number #}
            {% if posts.currentPage >= 3 and posts.currentPage <= posts.lastPage-3 %}
                {% for page in posts.currentPage-2..posts.currentPage+2 %}
                    <li class="page-item {{ posts.currentPage == page ? 'active' : null }}"><a class="page-link" href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): page }) }}">{{ page }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            {% elseif posts.currentPage < 3 %}
                {% for page in 1..posts.currentPage+2 %}
                    <li class="page-item {{ posts.currentPage == page ? 'active' : null }}"><a class="page-link" href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): page }) }}">{{ page }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            {% elseif posts.currentsPage <= posts.lastPage-2 %}
                {% for page in posts.currentPage-2..posts.lastPage %}
                    <li class="page-item {{ posts.currentPage == page ? 'active' : null }}"><a class="page-link" href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): page }) }}">{{ page }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            {# end: Page number #}
            {# Next page #}
            {% if posts.lastPage-2 > posts.currentPage %}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (posts.currentPage+1) }) }}"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {# Last page #}
            {% if posts.lastPage-2 > posts.currentPage %}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (posts.lastPage) }) }}"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></li>
            {% endif %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
        {# end: Pagination #}
```